# Dynamic import is not working on express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to implement a dynamic import inside a express.js router

now I have a bellow code

HelloWorldController.js

```js
export const helloWorld = function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world')
}
```

router.js

```js
export default async function (app) {
    app.use('/', await ( async function () {
        const helloWorldController = await import('./helloWorldController.js')

        const router: express.Router = express.Router()

        router
            .get('/', helloWorldController.helloWorld)
        return router
    })
}
```

server.js

```js
import express from 'express'
import router from './router.js'

const app = express()

router(app)

app.listen(3000, function(){
    logger.ready(`Web Server is running on port 3000`)
})
```

---

This is the result I'm getting when I run server.js

I have a 404 error

```
 GET / 404 18.761 ms - 25
```

---

This is working fine

router.js

```js
import * as helloWorldController './helloWorldController.js'
export default async function (app) {
    app.use('/', await ( async function () {
        const router: express.Router = express.Router()

        router
            .get('/', helloWorldController.helloWorld)
        return router
    })
}
```

---

** What am I doing wrong? **

Answer (score 0):

ES6 import syntax is not supported yet in node js,
try this syntax `const {express} = require("express")`

Comment: es6 is working well on my Node.js v14.17.3